# Как установить windows по сети?

Tags: windows, сеть

Есть ноут с вуросом-баннером, дисковод в нем сломан, загрузки с USB в биусе нет, осталась только установка по сети.

Так вот, как переустановить систему по сети?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если ноутбук поддерживает загрузку по сети, то Вам надо сделать на одном из компов - сервер BOOTP & TFTP.

Подробнее читайте тут - http://habrahabr.ru/post/49572/

Answer (score 1):

Может все таки пойти по более простому пути... Найти где нибудь внешний USB DVD-привод. И тогда без проблем переустановишь ОС :)

Answer (score 0):

С Windows server (2008/2012) можно развернуть службу развертки и найти boot.wim install.wim от нужной ОС. А дальше подключатся с клиента.